# iOS In-App Purchases restore previous purcases safely

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, payment, storekit

I have implemented an In-App Purchase in my app and I have two questions about it. This is the code I use:

```
- (IBAction)buyProduct1:(id)sender {
    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product1];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}

- (IBAction)restorePurchases:(id)sender {
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {

    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:

                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:

                //Can I be 100% sure that this method is only called when the product is bought?
                [self product1Bought:transaction];

                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:

                //What code should I have here to safely restore product1 if the product is bought?

                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:

                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

- (void)product1Bought:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
    NSString *string = @"Product1";
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:string forKey:@"Product1"];
    NSLog(@"Product1 is bought");
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
}
```

1.I was just wondering if I can be 100% sure that the productBought method is only called after a successfully purchase and not if anything strange happens and the product wasn't really purchased?

2.How can I check if product1 is purchased earlier so I can call the product1Bought method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
```

{

```
 if ([queue.transactions count] == 0)
 {
     UIAlertView *restorealert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@"Restore"
                                  message:@"There is no products purchased by you"
                                  delegate:self
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];

     [restorealert show];
     activityIndicator.hidden = YES;


 }
else
{
    NSString *productID;



    for(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions)
    {
     productID = transaction.payment.productIdentifier;
        NSLog(@"the product identifier is %@",productID);
```

}

here after completing your restore you can get the productId which you bought

Answer (score 1):

1) is working fine and the data will be available when user purchases it

2) for the early purchased items you can call this method under SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:

```
[self RestorePurchases];

-(void)RestorePurchases{
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}
```